# Passing value converted wrong to uint32_t in avr c

Tags: c, avr

I simulate my code for my atmega2560 in Atmel Studio 7.
I have a delay_ms function. I call it so:

```
delay_ms(150);
```

And I have this function

```
void delay_ms(uint32_t mstime){
    uint32_t tnow=millis();
    tnow+=mstime;
    while (tnow>=millis());
}
```

In the function mstime value is 9,830,400 which is in binary 1001 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000, 150 is in binary 1001 0110. Why it shifted 16bit to left?

Comment: @QiuZhou And where does the 65535 / 0xFFFF come from, millis()?

Comment: What size is `int` on that machine? do you have proper header with prototype for that function included?

Comment: @Gerhardh Atmega should be 16 bit `int` little endian. But endianess doesn't explain this.

Comment: atmega2560 is 8 bit avr.

Comment: In the header:
    void delay_ms(uint32_t mstime);

Comment: @Sketch Which is kind of irrelevant, what matters is the size of `int` (it's 16 bits on all 8 bit MCUs) and how the ISA prefers to handle stuff larger than 8 bits, endianess, which in case of AVR should be little endian.

Comment: Anyway, I suppose this could be related to some non-trivial software lib for handling 32 bit numbers and the debugger failing to understand how that lib does calling convention for such numbers. I think more context is necessary to answer - I'd start by disassembling this and see how the parameter is passed.

Comment: Here is a link to the simulator: https://ibb.co/hmr0qhw

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Answer Gerhardh’s questions directly and explicitly. For example, he asked “What size is `int` on that machine?”, and you answered “atmega2560 is 8 bit avr,” but that does not tell us what value would be printed for `sizeof(int)`. And he asked “do you have proper header with prototype for that function included?”, and you answered “In the header: void delay_ms(uint32_t mstime);” but that does not tell us whether that header is included in the source file that calls `delay_ms`.

Comment: how do you print the value? avr gcc converts it without any problems.

Comment: Are you debugging optimized code, per chance? Can you post the disassembly?

Comment: (Unrelated to your question, a tip is to replace `uint32_t counter = 0; // milliseconds` with `uint32_t counter_ms = 0;` Self-documenting code.)

Comment: Recompile your project with optimization disabled (-O0). Otherwise the compiler's optimizator can move variables between registers and the "watch" window could not display them properly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil int size is 2byte, and yes i didnt included the delay_ms header file. now it works. But i dont know why compiler doesnt say undefined function for delay_ms.

Comment: @AterLux yes its turned off default

Comment: @P__J__ i simulate it in AS7, and i saw in the watch window

Comment: @Lundin disassembly doesnt show intresting things for me :) avr registers are 8bit, and parameter sent by 16bit as i saw. btw now good.

Comment: Perhaps not for you, but since it's a lousy 8-bitter it can't handle 32 bit arithmetic without including a whole lot of software libs for that between the lines. And come up with a way to pass 32 bit numbers. What those libs and calling convention boil down to might reveal why it seems to toss around the bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per a comment from OP, `int` is two bytes, and a header that presumably declared `delay_ms` was not included. Then what happens is:

- When `delay_ms` is called, the compiler inserts a default declaration of `int delay_ms();`, per historic C behavior.
- Since this declaration of `delay_ms` does not have argument prototypes, the `150` in `delay_ms(150)` is passed as an `int`, which is two bytes.
- In the definition of `delay_ms`, the parameter is defined as `uint32_t`, which is four bytes. Thus, the function looks for four bytes of argument.
- The extra two bytes happened to contain zeros and, due to the endianness of the machine, were used as the low two bytes of the `uint32_t`, with the passed two bytes (0x0096) being used as the upper two bytes.
- This forms this 0x00960000 (9,830,400) value observed by the OP.

The solution is to include a declaration of `delay_ms` in the source file that calls the routine. Also, enable warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. The compiler likely warned about the use of `delay_ms` without a declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i wanted to know! 
All others, sorry for my bad english, some thing i didnt understanded well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but maybe #include <avr/io.h> also has a delay_ms function and it seems uint16_t parameter. I will check it.
I included my timer.h in the corresponding xxxx.c file, and now it works as well.

Comment: avr/io.h and includes hasnt delay_ms definition.